# How to access and store item by vector with multiple class in C++

Tags: c++, vector, methods, scope, stl

I want to use vector to store all `Record`. The `Record` class contains `student` and their age. It supposes to get the command and then call the specific method. However, when I compile it, it said "`t` is not declared". However, I have already declared as table `t`. How can I access the `private` `vector` without changing the visibility.

```
class student{
  public:
    int id;
    string name;
    student();
    student(int,string);
};

class Record{
  public:
    student student;
    int age;
};

class table{
  public:
    void Insert(student x,int y);
    void Print(table t)
  private:
    vector <Record> records;
};

void Insert(student x,int y){
    Record r;
    r.student=x;
    r.grade=y;
    t.records.push_back(r);
}

void Print(table t){
    sort( t.record.begin() , t.record.end() );
    vector<Record>::iterator itr;
    for( itr = t.record.begin() ; itr != t.record.end() ; itr++ )
          cout << (*itr).student.id << '\t' << (*itr).student.name << '\t' << (*itr).age << endl;
}

int main (){
    student x;
    table t;
    string command,name;
    int id,age;
    while ( cin >> command ){
        if (command=="Insert"){
            cin >> id >> name>> grade;
            student s(id,name);
            t.InsertStudent(s,grade);
        }else if (command == "Print"){
            t.Print(t);
        }else{return 0;
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> `t` was not declared in this scope in `t.records.push_back(r);`

I have capitalized the class name and the problem still exist.

Comment: What exactly is your error message? for what line? If you want to access a private member, create a getter function for it. You should not use the name of the class as a name of a variable instance of that class (student student in record class). I suggest using a capital case for class names.

Comment: You should find a good book and read introductory Object Oriented Programming material.  For example, `class Table` (o_weisman's right - capitalise your class names) should have `void print();`, then at file scope you should have `void Table::print() { ... }` and refer therein to `records` (without any `t.`).

Comment: The error message is 't'was not declared in this scope in "t.records.push_back(r);" this line. I have capitalised the class name and the problem still exist.

Comment: `t` is declared inside the `main` function, and so only visible there. The way you coded it, `Print` and `Insert` looks like free functions and not members of the class. If you listen to Tony and name them `Table::Insert` and `Table::Print` you can access the `records` member without needing the `t.` prefix. Also check the spelling - `record` or `records`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a significant number of problems with this code. So we'll address the 3 mistakes most closely related to your question: **How can I access the private vector without changing the visibility?**

1. You are calling: `t.InsertStudent(s,grade)`. Since you declare `table t`, that will try to call `class table`'s `InsertStudent` method. Which there isn't one. You probably intended to call the `Insert` method.
2. You define the *function* `void Insert(student x,int y)` which was likely intended as the *method* `void table::Insert(student, int y)`. Note the class scoping on the definition. Alternatively, you could remove the declaration, and just use the definition directly in class scope.
3. You are trying to call `t.records.push_back(r)` where `t` is not a global object that this *function* would have access to. But presuming from **2** that you intended to define this as a *method* you would not use an object name to access member variables, instead you could directly access the member variables: `records.push_back(r)`

I've tried to briefly explain how to fix stuff, but there are some underlying conceptual problems here that need to be addressed, which probably can't be addressed in a couple sentences. Please at least read through: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ before asking follow up questions. If any of my answer remains unclear after reading through that, feel free to comment below.
As far as other errors in the code start by looking over the line that the compiler issues the waning on. If you can't solve it using that feel free to open a new question posting the code and error.